# How can I further secure my system using 2 factor authentication?

Tags: security, two-factor-authentication

The title pretty much says it. I have been hearing more about 2 factor authentication, one-time passwords, hard-tokens, and other improved security features. With the decreasing security of using just a password, I want to know how I can improve my security on Ubuntu. I am using 14.04 LTS with Unity.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the open-source Pluggable Authentication Module (PAM) created by Google, known as the [Google Authenticator](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator). This module is available in the standard repositories, as well as from GitHub so that you can build from source. Coupled with the Android, iOS, or Blackberry App of the same name, it creates time-based, time-sensitive codes for authentication along with your password. Since it is a PAM module, it can be dropped in *pretty much anywhere*. Let's get started!

## Installing

To start, you can install the PAM with the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libpam-google-authenticator
```

Simple!

## Setting it up:

After it's installed, you will want to also install the corresponding mobile application for Android, iOS, or Blackberry (depending on your mobile platform). Each one is useless without the other. After you have the application you need for your mobile device, run the following in a terminal:

```
google-authenticator
```

This will start by asking you a few questions The first one is the only one which you must answer "Yes" to, and it asks if you want the codes to be time-based. After that, read each question and make the choice that makes the most sense to you.

Upon completing the initial set-up, you will see a *very* large QR code in your terminal, as well as some other information. The line that says "Your New Secret Key Is:" is a much needed line if you don't want to use the QR code for pairing your device, so don't close this window until you are set-up! The "scratch codes" this gives you are also important, as they are what you will use to log-in if you lose your mobile device. Write them down and store them somewhere safe.

Now, on your mobile device, open your Google Authenticator application and select "Set up account". You can either scan the QR code that was generated, or select "Use provided key". If you scan the QR code, everything will be automatically saved under an account named "your_user@your_host". However, if you select "Use provided key", you will have to enter a name, key, and type of token manually. The name can be anything you wish. The key would be the secret key previously generated. The type would be the default time-based. After setting it up, you will see the account on the main pane of the Google Authenticator app, as well as a circle-shaped timer next to it. That timer depletes every 30 seconds, and a new code is generated.

## Enabling it!

Here comes the magic. Since this is a PAM module, it can be used in a variety of places. I will walk through adding authentication to `sudo` requests, SSH log-ins, and lightdm log-in. However, after reading this tutorial, you will be able to enable it elsewhere based on the same techniques.

### SSH

I'm doing this one first because there is an extra step. The first thing you need to do is to edit your SSH config file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Search for the line that says:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

and change the "no" to a "yes".

Now, you need to edit the PAM module for ssh:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pam.d/sshd
```

At the very end of this file, add the following line:

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
```

The "nullok" argument tells the system to **not** request a verification code if a user has not set-up two factor authentication. After that edit, go ahead and restart your ssh service:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

### `sudo` Requests

Edit the PAM file for `sudo`:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pam.d/sudo
```

Add the following line at the very end:

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
```

Now every `sudo` request will ask for a verification code as well as a password.

### LightDM (GUI Log-In)

Edit the PAM file for LightDM:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pam.d/lightdm
```

Add the following line at the very end:

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
```

That's it! Everytime you log-in through the GUI, it will ask for a verification code after your password.

### System-Wide and TTY Log-In

Even if you enable the above methods, it still won't ask for a verification code if you switch over to a TTY with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd>. To fix this, edit the `common-auth` PAM file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pam.d/common-auth
```

and add the following line to the very end:

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
```

### **Note:** Since this common-auth file is included in all other auth type files, you need to remove the auth required lines from the other files. Otherwise, it will ask for the verification code twice and not allow you to log-in after.

## Wrap-Up

As you could see, it was pretty easy to add this authentication in. If you use a display manager other than LightDM, you could easily just change the lightdm line above accordingly. Since your mobile device and your system shared this secret key already, they should always be in-sync. There is no interaction with Google servers, or any other internet resource for this set-up. Even if both devices were completely offline, the verification codes that show up in your application will be correct. Whenever you need to log-in through one of the methods you've enabled, just make sure to open up your mobile application and grab the current verification code.

## Have fun!!

Comment: Commenting for later notes.  Well written!  +1  =)

Comment: +1 - this is both really cool and well-written.

Comment: And then your phone decides it has no more power and wants to shutdown. :)  +1

Comment: That's what the scratch codes are for, @Rinzwind :D

Comment: Added in instructions for enabling two-factor on TTY.

Comment: @ThomasW. Add an answer :D

Comment: @TheBrownOne Thank you for such a well-written solution. Regarding your note under the **System-Wide and TTY Log-In**: Are you saying that if I do this step, I should _omit_ the steps for **SSH**, **sudo Requests** and **LightDM (GUI Log-In)**? Also, have I correctly understood that any user who has _not_ set up Google Authenticator will not notice any difference, even if he is an administrator? Finally, how does a user turn off two-factor authentication?

Comment: Both of those statements are correct. However, you still need to enable challenge responses in your sshd file.

Comment: @TheBrownOne Thank you for your reply. I have tested this in VirtualBox with two test accounts. (It appears that you can turn off two-factor authentication by deleting `~/.google-authenticator`). One account works for login, while the other ignores two-factor and allows login without it. Both accounts work for `sudo`. Neither account works for `gksudo`, which asks for the password and then fails. Do you have an easy answer for the two problems, or shall I post a new question? Thanks again for your time and effort.

Comment: I will investigate and help you with this later today, a little busy at the moment

Comment: @TheBrownOne I've just realised why the login doesn't work with one of the accounts. It has an encrypted home folder, so LightDM is unable to see `~/.google-authenticator`. There must be a way around this, but I haven't (yet) figured out how. So, it's only the `gksudo` problem that remains. Also, `pkexec` works (although it's a poor replacement for `gksudo`).

Answer (score 1):

[FreeOTP](https://fedorahosted.org/freeotp/) is an open-source alternative to the Google Authenticator Android app on Google Play (whose current code is not open source). FreeOTP is available on [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.fedorahosted.freeotp) (and [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.fedorahosted.freeotp)).