# Ssh safe enough?

Tags: ssh, ip, raspberrypi

This question is about ssh

Hi i web server for my site, I use ssh :).
I know i can port forward port 22 but is it safe enough?
Let's say i use a password that takes a million years to crack or something.
Will it be safe then or will someone be able to login with some trick?

Thanks

Comment: Disabled root login , only login as sudo.

Comment: See [How to harden an SSH server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2271/how-to-harden-an-ssh-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use keys and disable password authentication. It will get rid of most of the authentication attempts and you are safe enough. SSH protocol itself is secure.

Comment: Huh so i have to disable it but i need the password right?

Comment: If you use keys, you don't need passwords.

Comment: So that is way safer than a super complicated password?

Comment: Yes. Until the key is safe and/or protected by passhprase. You should be safe even with complicated password, but keys are preferred.

Comment: Thanks so much!, i have one more question sorry :( But what if i make a passcode as long as a key is that just as safe as a key?

Comment: It would be roughly 256 characters if you compare to 2048 b long keys. I don't think you want that :) And with keys you will get rid of most of the brute-force attacks as I mentioned before.

Comment: Oh yeah i do not want to type that but what if i save it behind a password just like a key? Because i want to be able to login from all different places around the world :)

Comment: As always. Until it will get compromised. You can also carry the key with you. There are HSMs (Hardware security module), Yubikey. Many possibilities.

Comment: Thanks so much that you are still answering my probably stupid questions but what do you mean with compromised you mean like being stolen or brute forced? Thanks so much! i am new to all of this :)

Comment: stolen, copied (key from HSM can't be copied so when it will get stolen, you will know). Such long password/key basically can't be brute-forced.

Comment: Thanks so much! i guess i am going for a password i am a simple guy and i assure you it will not get stolen or copied :)

Comment: How do i mark this threat as solved by you?

Comment: There should be a tick on the left side of this post [./]

Comment: You can also enable 2 factor authentication to further harden it.

Comment: @TheBrownOne Setting 2 factor is usually quite complicated, but thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: I have a nice, easy write up for it [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/726969/how-can-i-further-secure-my-system-using-2-factor-authentication/726970#726970)

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to change de default port 22 to another one.

Under linux, edit this file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, change the port number by editing this line `Port 22`, save and restart SSH `/etc/init.d/ssh restart`

Comment: it is usually more complicated than above. It is "security through obscurity". If you are targeted by an attack, using `nmap` is matter of seconds to find your "safe" "another" port.

Comment: @Jakuje: I'm not saying that changing SSH port is THE solution for maximum safety, just an additional method to avoid basic attacks.