# Set another password automatically every day for a user session

Tags: command-line, bash, password, cron, session

I would like to configure my computer to have a session whose password would change automatically every day. The password needn't be very strong, and must be easy to reconstruct mentally (I will think about a mathematical formula to return a number as function of the date, which would be hard enough to crack). **The sake of the thing is that I would be the only one to be able to reconstruct current day's password** and my little brother, which is 12 years old, would have to ask for the password if he needs the computer that day, since I sometimes come back late in the evening, and I can't monitor him when I'm not at home.

I thought to add a few lines of code in a script which would be run once when the computer is turned on, even before a session is opened. Does root's crontab with the @reboot flag make the job ?

It may be a line such as `passwd "example"$(date "+%w%d")` (the password generated would be more complex, but that's an example), but let say that I want root to perform that action, and I don't find in the manual a way to change the password for a specific user. I would like to write something similar to `echo "example"$(date "+%w%d") | passwd --user mylittlebrother`, but the option --user does not exist...

How should I proceed ? Is there a better way to do that ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: How about you add him as a separate user? This way you could easily control his access, e.g. with [timekpr](https://launchpad.net/~mjasnik/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) (disable guest access!).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/399122/158442 - for setting the password

Comment: It might be more secure to setup 2FA: https://askubuntu.com/q/726969/158442. Your brother might get lucky and guess the password once he figures out the pattern, but guessing the 2FA code would be a shade harder.

Comment: Oh : the 2FA seems interesting, but in my case, I don't want to use an additional device. I am confident enough to find a pattern which would be strong enough for a 12 years old guy. I'm a student in a polytechnique university, so I find a way. Let's say the first four digits in cosh(day of week times day in month divided by the year). I always have a calculator nearby.

Comment: See [How do I restrict my kids' computing time?](https://askubuntu.com/a/70277/178692) for a way to do time-based access using PAM without needing a 3rd party PPA